# How to XSS filtering variable?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter 2.1.3 with Friendly URL (.htaccess).

In Controller:

```
public function confirm($key) {
   var_dump($this->input->get());
}
```

But link _http://site.com/confirm/12345 returns "boolean false".

How to enable Query strings in URL, or how to filtering $key ?

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|files|templates)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive `key` as the function argument, so you can do this:

```
public function confirm($key) {
   echo $key;
}
```

`http://site.com/confirm/12345` will echo `12345`.

Filtering of characters in this can be done via `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in `config.php`.

If you want to receive it as a `GET` parameter and want to perform XSS filtering on it, the URL needs to be

`http://site.com/confirm?key=12345` and in your controller

```
public function confirm() {
   echo $this->input->get('key', TRUE);   // true implies XSS filtering
}
```

The second method requires `$config['enable_query_strings']` to be set to `TRUE`.